# Is "public image" a common phrase to refer to something like public "ego"?

Tags: vocabulary

[From the Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/public%20image)

> Definition of public image = the opinion that many people have of a person
>
> The scandal ruined his public image.

I guess I understand the meaning and the usage of it.

As per [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ego), "ego" means

> your idea or opinion of yourself, especially your feeling of your own importance and ability

That's how someone think themselves are. For example, Tom thinks he is a good husband, so his **ego** is a good husband; Harrison thinks he is a successful businessman, his ego is a successful businessman.

Is there a phrase to refer to public idea of someone?

Suppose Tom and Harrison are famous movie stars, so almost all movies fans in the world know them.

Almost all movies fans think Tom cares about his family, for them, Tom's **public ego / outside appearance / public image** is a good husband and a good father.

In contrast, for those movies fans, Harrison is not a good husband or a good father, no matter wether Harrison really cares about his family in real life.

The way people consider Tom is because Tom has been working on it. He posted lots of family photos, he attends to public activities with his family.

Is "public image" a common phrase to refer to something like "public ego", "outside appearance" or some other phrases that indicate the way public view the celebrity as.

Comment: Maybe you need to edit the first sentence of your question? It doesn't make sense at the moment.

Comment: This is not the way 'ego' is used in colloquial English.