# correct/common usage of "ego"

Tags: word-usage

[Is "public image" a common phrase to refer to something like public "ego"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/248069/109190) says

> That's how someone think themselves are. For example, Tom thinks he is a good husband, so his **ego** is a good husband; Harrison thinks he is a successful businessman, his ego is a successful businessman.

That's what I understand from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ego)

However, @Katy claims this without any explanation or suggestion.

> This is not the way 'ego' is used in colloquial English.

What the correct/common usage of "ego"?

Comment: Shouldn't this have been edited to the older question? Here you are asking how to use the word "ego" and in the older question you are asking if "public image", "outside image" and "public ego"  carry similar meanings, but it stemmed from your understanding of "ego". If  someone answers here, the older question will become redundant.

Comment: Look at **examples** of how the word "ego" is used. See Lexico [*‘Being in a relationship is **a boost to the ego**, and being dumped is devastating to it - at least if you're me.’*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ego) and “*‘A car, psychologists tell us, is an extension of **man's ego**.’*”

Comment: Katy is correct. That isn't how "ego" is used. Try searching for the term at Google books. There will be hundreds of examples of its use, most within the realm of psychology.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thank you. "ego" is a term in what field?

Comment: @WXJ96163  Field? Quoting myself, "most within the realm of psychology."

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you. This post is indeed to discuss the usage of "ego" while another post is probably not about "ego" at all. I don't know what the correct term is, that's why I asked [that one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/248069/109190). Would you please give some hint about that?